# Return a custom data type from Ant to Maven

Tags: maven, ant, maven-2, maven-3, ant-contrib

I have an Ant script called from Maven to perform some tasks. One such task is to read a text file linewise and use its content to perform text replacements on a huge set of files.  The text file will be in the following format on each line:

```
name#URL#Title
```

Ant task for this is as follows:

```
<target name="update-urls" depends="load-ant-contrib"> 
        <loadfile property="file" srcfile="${mapping.file}"/>

        <foreach param="file.entry" list="${file}" delimiter="${line.separator}" target="update-template"></foreach>
</target>

   <!--Get the name,url and title of each line-->     

          <target name="update-template">

  <propertyregex property="name"
                       input="${file.entry}"
                       regexp="(.*)#(.*)#(.*)$"
                       select="\1"/>
        <propertyregex property="url"
                       input="${file.entry}"
                       regexp="(.*)#(.*)#(.*)$"
                       select="\2"/>
        <propertyregex property="title"
                       input="${file.entry}"
                       regexp="(.*)#(.*)#(.*)$"
                       select="\3"/>
        <echo>${template.name}</echo>

<!--Use title and url to match and replace the URL with the URL in text file-->

            <replaceregexp byline="true"
                           match="(&lt;title&gt;${title} *&lt;/title&gt;.*)${url} *"
                           replace="\1../modified-path/${name}.zip"
                           flags="g"
                           encoding="utf-8"
                    >
<!--Following are the files on which replacement has to happen-->

              <fileset dir="${huge.set.of.files}/items">
                <include name="**/info.xml"/>
              </fileset>
            </replaceregexp>
          </target>
```

Since this needs to work on huge set of files, the above solution is not very efficient.  I have coded a mutithreaded solution for it in Java which takes up multiple regex expressions(name, value pairs) at once.I've integrated it into my maven project as a mojo.

I'm having trouble  with two things:

1. Framing a data-type to contain a **list of name, url, title triplets** in Ant.
2. If I'm successful with step 1., how to return this data structure to POM from where the Ant task got called and decode this data structure to be able to access each element's name, url and title separately..

Can someone guide me on how to go about this..

Comment: Are you able modify the large set file in first place for all the entries of the text file?

Comment: Yes. But currently for each entry, it reads all the files once to check which file has the matching pattern. I have a better solution but having trouble fitting it in here..

Comment: You like to replace all the contents of text file at once on the large set? Is this main issue? Any what is your better solution and trouble applying it here?

Comment: Text file is just an input to perform replacements. Replacement is not an issue. It works fine when I create a POM.xml with required parameters. Problem is doing it from an Ant task.

Comment: Reading all the data line by line and replacing them across all the files can easily be done in `ant` if you write a small custom task in `java` and call that custom task from `ant` script, at least, that is how I prefer if it is taking too much with default tasks.